# Line crossing detection program does not work

Tags: python, geometry

I have this type of code:

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1])
​
    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]
​
    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

But then whe i am trying to run this function with these parameters

```
line1 = [(100, 200), (390, 286)]
line2 = [(120, 256),
 (166.05304970014424, 275.47091711543254)]
​intrsct = line_intersection(line1, line2)
```

I get **True**, but these lines are not crossing each other. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Where did you get that formula?  It's clearly not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will determine if the two lines will cross, assuming they are extended infinitely in both directions. It's useless for determining if two line segments will cross. That's more work. See https://geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the equations of this [site](https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/Geometry%20Concepts%20part%202:%20%20Line%20Intersection%20and%20its%20Applications#:%7E:text=Line%2DLine%20Intersection,-One%20of%20the&text=To%20find%20the%20point%20at,two%20unknowns%2C%20x%20and%20y.&text=Finally%2C%20divide%20both%20sides%20by,y%20can%20be%20derived%20similarly.). This will return `False` if lines are parallel. In your case, they are not, hence why you get `True`.